# How to show certain list elements by number of rows

Tags: r

I have a list with 3000 elements. Each element has 18 columns and a different number of rows. I want to see only the list elements with more than 50 rows, so I tried to wirte a code with lapply.

For a single dataframe i tried

`test <- data_frame[1:nrow(data_frame) > 50, ]`

and it worked. So I tried to implement this code into a function with lapply:

`test <- lapply(data_list, function(x) x[1:nrow(x) > 50, ])`

but I get the Error: "Error in 1:nrow(x) : argument of length 0".

Do you know what I`m doing wrong? Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sapply(rr, nrow) > 5` produces a logical vector (`FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, ...` specifying which elements in `rr` has more than five rows. This vector can then be use to extract tose elements from the list.

```
set.seed(1)
rr <- replicate(6, 
  as.data.frame(matrix(1:(sample(2:6, 1)*2), ncol=2)),
  simplify=FALSE)

# Find and extract the dataframes with more than 5 rows
rr[sapply(rr, nrow) > 5]
```

Comment: Could you explain what you're doing here @AkselA and how it resolves the issue? See the other answer as an example of the level of detail that's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason why `lapply()` doesn't work is because the `nrow()` is being applied to a list, whereas it needs to be applied to a data frame / tibble. I tried to replicate your situation where there is a purrr solution.

Here there is a list of data frames with different number of rows - `map()` applies the function `nrow()` to each element in the list, and the `nrow` result returned is then tested against the `>50` criteria - which returns a logical vector to be indexed against the original list. Would this solution work for your problem?

```
df_1 <- data.frame(matrix(1:3600, nrow = 200, ncol = 18))
df_2 <- data.frame(matrix(1:2700, nrow = 150, ncol = 18))
df_3 <- data.frame(matrix(1:900, nrow = 50, ncol = 18))

your_list <- list(df_1,df_2,df_3)

your_list[purrr::map(your_list,nrow) > 50]
```